# BeautifulSoup - How to extract info from deeper layers of html

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup to scrape some real estate data and having trouble getting to what I need which are several href links that are deep in the .

http://www.mls.com/Search/New-York.mvc

To make the code stable, I've started with a parent that is two steps above my target  that I need:

```
area_links = soup.findAll('ul', class_="sub-section-list", limit=2)
```

now I have a ResultSet element but have failed in getting anything but errors out of it.

I've tried a number of arguments using `area_links.findAll` and `findAllNext`

I need to extract the links to the different metro areas so I can then dig into those.

Comment: it seems this page use JavaScript to add content and BeautifulSoup can't run JavaScript to get it. You may have to use Selenium to control real web browser which can run JavaScript. Or you have to find url used by JavaScript to get data and use this url to get HTML or JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer concise [css selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) to target the `a` tags of interest:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('http://www.mls.com/Search/New-York.mvc')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
links = ['http://www.mls.com' + i['href'] for i in soup.select('.sub-section-list a')]
print(links)
```

---

For yours, you need to loop the returned list and find the child `a` tags and extract the `href` attributes:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('http://www.mls.com/Search/New-York.mvc')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
area_links = soup.find_all('ul', class_="sub-section-list", limit=2)
for area in area_links:
    print(['http://www.mls.com' + i['href'] for i in area.find_all('a')])
```